# TCL Expect. How to get specific symbols from output?

Tags: tcl, expect

Has very little experience in programming and allmost no expirience in TCL Expect, but forced to use it.
I has output like that:

```
SMG2016-[CONFIG]-SIP-USERS> add user 1200011 adm.voip.partner.ru 0
Creating new Sip-User.
'SIP USER' [00] ID [1]:
                      name:                  Subscriber#000
                      IPaddr:                0.0.0.0
                      SIP domain:            adm.voip.partner.ru
                      dynamic registration:  off
                      number:                1200011
                      Numplan:               0
                      number list:
                         00)                 ---
                         01)                 none
                         02)                 none
                         03)                 none
                         04)                 none
                      AON number:
                      AON type number:       subscriber
                      profile:               0
                      category:              1
                      access cat:            0
                      auth:                  none
                      cliro:                 off
                      pbxprofile:            0
                      access mode:           on
                      lines:                 1
                      No src-port control:   off
                      BLF usage:             off
                      BLF subscribers:       10
                      Intercom mode:         sendonly
                      Intercom priority:     3
```

So i need to put in variable 00 from the 'SIP USER' [00] string, and the number in bracers could be up to four digits in row.

How shoud i do this? Any help please?

UPD:
Done this, works for me, even while having trouble with first zero.

```
expect -indices -re "'SIP USER' .{1}(\[0-9]{2,4}).{1}"
set userid [string trimleft $expect_out(1,string) "0"]
```

Comment: Break the input into lines, then use regexp to parse specific strings out of specific known lines.

Comment: So, one of the parts you want is the `00`. Anything else? Being specific as to what you want (i.e., which field or part of the line) helps a lot.